# Dump sql file to ClearDB in Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a sql file that I want to be dumped into a MySQL database that I have in Heroku using the ClearDB addon.  When dumping in local I do the following:

```
mysql -u my_user -p mydatabasename < my_dump_file.sql
```

However, I don't have any clue on how to dump it to the Heroku MySQL database. All I know is this address:

```
mysql://b5xxxxx7:37xxxad@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_xxxxxx?reconnect=true
```

But if I try to do:

```
mysql://b5xxxxx7:37d8faad@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_xxxxxx?reconnect=true < my_dump_file.sql
```

I get `No such file or directory`.

How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: When dumping in local you probably do `>` and not `<`, as the latter will actually restore and overwrite `mydatabasename`.

Comment: You don't "dump into", you "dump out of" a database. Then you "restore" a database from a dump.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this

```
mysql --host=us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com --user=b5xxxxx7 --password=37d8faad --reconnect heroku_xxxxxx < my_dump_file.sql
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I didn't use the command line, but it worked perfectly when I connected remotely with Sequel Pro. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: use `heroku config` to get the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL which contains the info you need for this command, in the format: `mysql://user:password@host/heroku_db?reconnect=true`. In this case: `mysql://b5xxxxx7:37d8faad@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_xxxxxx?reconnect=true`

Comment: I tried following your comment but it gave me this error:
`REFERENCES command denied to user 'baexxxxxxxxxxx'@'ec2-54-165-50-141.compute-1.amazonaws.com' for table 'ycdb.recipe' `

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I got: `ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 4: Access denied for user 'bexxxxxxxxxxxxxx@'%' to database 'xxxxxxxx'`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work for me on the new version of mysql. So I tried following code:

```
mysql -h us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com -u b5xxxxx7 -p heroku_xxxxxx < my_dump_file.sql
```

and then it asks your password.

Comment: I get access denied although I checked my password and made sure to enter it correctly.

Comment: `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bXXXXXXXXX'@'ip-10-0-6-79.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting errors when I typed it all at once so I broke it down into small steps first I entered my MySQL details like so:

```
mysql --host=us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net --user=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx --password=xxxxxxxx --reconnect
```

then once I got in I changed to the database like so:

mysql>  `use heroku_xxxxxxxxxx;`

then I now imported the SQL file like so:

mysql> `source path/to/file.sql;`

Answer (score 0):

I try all the answers above, but none work.

Then I read [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73672), and I conclude that I need to try it on CMD (previously I use Windows PowerShell admin).

No more errors in code.

I used this code (provided in the previous comment)

```
mysql -h us-xxxxxx.cleardb.com -u b7xxxxxxx -p heroku_df32xxxxxxx < dbname.sql
```

Comment: Is this supposed to answer the question at the top of the page? If so please rephrase to make the answering part more obvious.