# upload mysql DB from my localhost to Heroku Clear DB

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I create an app in heroku with the ClearDB add-on and PHP as language. Following the Heroku-ClearDB documentation guidelines I try to upload and existing localhost-DB created in MySQL with PHPMyAdmin ->

I execute in the console:

```
heroku addons:add cleardb:ignite --fork=mysql://user:pw@localhost/db_name
```

and everything looks fine but when I go to my app in heroku and I select the DB in the Dashboard the DB is empty.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803496/dump-sql-file-to-cleardb-in-heroku

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the `--fork` option tries to download the database from the ClearDB side and it can't get access to your local database - it's designed to fork databases from a globally available location.

You should copy the database manually via dump and restore as described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111224/6678.